# Finding the last used cell on worksheet and copying row into another worksheet?

Tags: c#, excel, copy-paste

any answere would be very much appreciated.
My question is as follow:

Is this the correct way to determin the last non-empty cell/row of my excel worksheet?

```
xl.Worksheet sh;
        int lastRow;
        int fullRow;

        sh = xlApp.Workbooks.get_Item("myExcelFile").Worksheets.get_Item("MySheet");
        fullRow = sh.Rows.Count;
        lastRow = sh.Cells[fullRow, 1].End(xl.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```

And if this is indeed correct how do I take my row and copy it into another worksheet. To be more specifict, the first empty cell of column A.
I know that i must use a command that is something like this:

```
lastRow.EntireRow.Copy(FirstEmptyCell);
```

Being a int type i cannot copy it to my other sheet.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
lastRow = sh.Cells[fullRow, 1].End(xl.XlDirection.xlUp).Row;
```

here, `lastRow` is an `int` so you can't use it as an object on your next line:

```
lastRow.EntireRow.Copy(FirstEmptyCell); // int doesn't have an EntireRow property
```

What you *can* do is combine the two into a single line:

```
Excel.Range myLastRow;
myLastRow = sh.Cells[sh.Rows.Count, 1].End(xl.xlDirection.Up).EntireRow;
```

now `myLastRow` is the entire row that you want to copy.

```
myLastRow.Copy(destination);
```

Comment: Wow, thank you for the fast response and for helping me out.
I'm happy to say that my row has been copied and now ready to be moved to my destination.

After it is fully functional I will post the code and what it looks like here so that anybody who is having trouble with this same thing might have an example to work off.

Thanks a lot again. Your answere is much appreciated and accepted aswell !!!

Comment: Not a problem - if your code is fully functional - I'd perhaps suggest posting it to [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) where people can offer advice and suggestions for improvements :)

Comment: I will surely do that because any advice and any help would be very much appreciated and useful.

The project I am working on now is basically being transposed from VBA code to C# code because i want to make it as a program so it doesn't use any "exterior elements"

It's more or less a macro and I have a few dynamic elements in it, and I've been struggling with finding my last row dynamically and setting/copying it :)

You can't imagine how happy I was to see your reply !

Comment: Doing your first VBA to C# rewrite is always..... interesting.... lol. Good luck with it all :)

Comment: Thank you :)
If you have any ideas or insights on the matter please let me know, I'm always happy to learn new things :)

Comment: When you reach 20rep there's a chat room called "VBA Lounge" that you can come and talk in. A couple of guys in there created a popular add-in called "RubberDuck" for VBA and they are great for any VBA/C# related stuff.